# Why does my donut look like n64 graphics?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d

I'm using three.js to render a few geometries on a plane with some basic lighting but why does my donut shape look so low res? It does not look very smooth?
[image: Donut Image]

Comment: You presumably didn't use very many polygons?

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the mesh of your donut doesn't have a lot of polygons, hence the pointy silhouette. The reason why it's looking normal on the surface, is because of smooth shading. I assume you constructed your donut as a [Torus](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry), in which case you can increase the number `tubularSegments` and `radialSegments` to get a smoother outline.

Comment: Yes , you were right. I tried before increasing the number of Segments  for both parameters you mentioned but the mesh still looked pointy with few polygons. I think I may have tried to many ( new. THREE.TorusBufferGeometry(.3, .2, 500, 500) . In any case my donut is smooth and looks great. Thanks!

Comment: You can accept my answer to indicate that!